# Normality of pullback of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint normal topological spaces and, $A\subseteq X$ a closed subset with $f:A\rightarrow Y$  a continuous function. Please help me to show in detail that the pullback of $X$ and $Y$ which is the quotient space $X+_f Y$, is a normal space.

Many Thanks

Comment: the pullback is the adjunction space?

Comment: Sounds like you mean push out?

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of proof, based on [Dugundji](http://www.southalabama.edu/mathstat/personal_pages/carter/Dugundji.pdf) (Topology, p. 146/147):

let $p$ be the quotient map from $X + Y$ to $X \cup_f Y$, the adjunction space of $X$ to $Y$ via $f$. If $F_1, F_2$ are disjoint and closed in $X \cup_f Y$, then $Y \cap p^{-1}[F_i]$ $i=1,2$ are closed and disjoint in $Y$, so there are $V_i$ open in $Y$ such that $Y \cap p^{-1}[F_i] \subseteq V_i, i=1,2$ and $\overline{V_1} \cap \overline{V_2} = \emptyset$. Then both $p[\overline{V_i}]$ are closed in $X \cup_f Y$ (check this!) and both $X\cap p^{-1}[F_i \cup p[\overline{V_i}]]$ are closed and disjoint in $X$, so these sets can be separated in $X$ by disjoint open subsets $U_i$ in $X$. Then check that for both $i$, $F_i \subseteq p[(U_i \setminus A) \cup V_i]$ and the latter sets are open and disjoint in $X \cup_f Y$.

Comment: An alternative proof is in G2 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-901-introduction-to-topology-fall-2004/lecture-notes/notes_g.pdf)